# Switching between texts with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Say I have two words I want to keep replacing with each other.

Right now I have a word fading in i.e

```
$('.js--switch').waypoint(function(direction){

    $('.js--switch').addClass('animated fadeIn');   


}, {
    offset:'50%'
});
```

so my text is fading in fine.However I want it to fade in and then once it is done fading in, replace this with another text. After that fades in it goes to the original text. How can I do this? I tried using .replaceWith, but then my second text just appears and my first text doesent come at all.

Comment: Could you replace the text a second time with the original text?